# How could I get that reward amount of the nominator

Tags: polkadot, staking, pallet-staking, npos

As a developer，I want to use the interface to search this information: which can get the amount which nominator has been rewarded at every era and staking?

Comment: What is "the interface"? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is to inspect the `Rewarded` event and find the one that corresponds to your nominator of choice. Some useful links to docs/tools:

https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_staking/enum.Event.html#variant.Rewarded
https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events#rewardedaccountid32-u128
https://polkadot.subscan.io/event?address=&module=staking&event=rewarded&startDate=&endDate=&startBlock=&endBlock=&timeType=date&version=9281

Comment: how to use api.events.staking.Rewarded.is to get reward?  like this: let event:IEventLike={
   index:9281,
   method:"staking",
   section:"rewarded",
  };
  const nominatorReward = api.events.staking.Rewarded.is(event)
  console.log(nominatorReward)